# #1305 - FUNCTION ANY_VALUE does not exist

Tags: mysql, xampp

estoy replicando una base de datos de servidor linux en mi laptop, pero en las consultas ocurre un error de que `#1305 - FUNCTION ANY_VALUE does not exist` cuya consulta lo realize yo mismo en `servidor linux` la cual corre sin problemas, acabo de instalarme la version de `xampp 3.2.2` y `phpmyadmin 4.8.4` la cual es mas reciente y estaba incluido en `XAMPP`.

```html
SELECT
    estado AS estado,
    ANY_VALUE(ano) AS ano,
    ANY_VALUE(fecha) AS NAME
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        f.estadoF AS estado,
        YEAR(p.fechaP) AS ano,
        MONTHNAME(p.fechaP) AS fecha
    FROM
        pagos p
    INNER JOIN factura f ON
        p.idFactura = f.idFactura
    WHERE
        (f.estadoF = 'Pagado') AND(
            p.fechaP BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
        )
    GROUP BY
        p.fechaP
) pagos
GROUP BY
    mes
```

En cuanto a las versiones de `MySQL` en el servidor es `MySQL 5.7.*` y en el `XAMPP` es `MariaDB 10.1.*` la cual funciona bien, pero no reconoce `ANY_VALUE()`.

Alguna sugerencia de ¿Actualizar u Optimizar sentencia?

Comment: Sugerencia que en ambas uses el mismo gestor, o que verifiques en la documentación de mariadb si soporta esa función

Comment: Revisa este enlace es oficial y menciona que esa función no está implementada aún en maria https://jira.mariadb.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MDEV-12481

Comment: sin embargo revisa este otro hilo, donde mencionan sobre este punto pero en mariaDB 10.3 https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10426